# Iframe window.innerWidth shows 280000 in iOS when iframe width set in percentage

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, iframe

I have an html page in which there is an iframe,
The iframe's width attribute is kept in percentage, say 100%.

Now, the iframe loads an another page inside it and in that page, using javascript's `window.innerWidth`the width of the iframe is queried.
The width acquired by this is `280000` whereas it should give some actual pixel width of the iframe.

This only happens in iOS and only when the width of the iframe is set in percentage.

Is this some iOS bug and is there any way to get around this?

Thanks.